# How can I format pubDate to HH:MM AM/PM?

Tags: xslt, rss

Is there an easy way to format an RSS pubDate

```
<pubDate>Thu, 28 May 2015 08:00:00 -0400</pubDate>
```

into:

```
8:00AM
```

I'm not all that familiar with date formatting, and I can't for the life of me recall what that time format is, so Google isn't helping me any.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="pubDate">
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="substring(., 18, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring(., 21, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h12" select="($h + 11) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="am.pm" select="substring('AMPM', 1 + 2*(number($h) > 11), 2)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($h12, ':', $m, $am.pm)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

General date parsing is quite complex.  There were some discussions to add the opposite of fn:format-date() to the standard XPath library 3.0, but did not succeed because of the complexity of the task in the generic case.

I am afraid you are limited to string manipulation here, which in your case is not too bad.  For instance:

```
<xsl:variable name="hours"   select="xs:integer(substring($input, 18, 2))"/>
<xsl:variable name="minutes" select="substring($input, 21, 2)"/>
<xsl:sequence select="
   if ( $hours ge 12 ) then
      concat($hours - 12, ':', $minutes, 'PM')
   else
      concat($hours, ':', $minutes, 'AM')"/>
```

Error management has not been added, up to you to add some, depending on how good and homogeneous is your input.

Comment: I believe the correct result for an input of `12:00:00` is `12:00PM`, not `0:00PM`. Similarly, `00:00:00` should produce `12:00AM`, not `0:00AM`.

Comment: Maybe. I don't know the requirements. But the idea is there, up to JesseEarley to adapt it to its needs.